# How do I change my MAC address on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, mac-address, spoofing

I'm trying using macchanger (`ip link set wls1 down`, `macchanger -r wls1` and `ip link set wls1 up`) but it doesn't work. When I try to connect to my wifi the MAC address is set to the default value... It's strange because whet I put down the interface the Network Manager seems to be still connected to the LAN and I have to disconnect it manually. I've tried disabling the Network Manager and reenabling it after the MAC changing but nothing happened...

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux with Xfce btw

Answer (score 0):

Command:

> /etc/init.d/networking stop
>
> ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:01:02:03:04:08
>
> /etc/init.d/networking start

Configuration:

> MACADDR=12:34:56:78:90:ab

For detailed information, please refer to this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux)